# Get all the Font Styles Available for a Font Family in c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, dialog, custom-controls

I want to get all the font styles available for a fontfamily.By using    ff.IsStyleAvailable i can check each style.But there are specific styles for different types of fonts.How can i fetch the styles available for a font family.Currently im using a custom font dialog that is populated with the fontfamily items.Please help me out to add a font style selection control,I have posted the code for the fontlist below.

```
public class FontListBox : ListBox
{
    private List<Font> _fonts = new List<Font>();
    private Brush _foreBrush;

    public FontListBox()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        ItemHeight = 20;
        foreach (FontFamily ff in FontFamily.Families)
        {
            // determine the first available style, as all fonts don't support all styles
            FontStyle? availableStyle = null;
            foreach (FontStyle style in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle)))
            {
                if (ff.IsStyleAvailable(style))
                {
                    availableStyle = style;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (availableStyle.HasValue)
            {
                Font font = null;
                try
                {
                    // do your own Font initialization here
                    // discard the one you don't like :-)
                    font = new Font(ff, 12, availableStyle.Value);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                if (font != null)
                {
                    _fonts.Add(font);
                    Items.Add(font);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (_fonts != null)
        {
            foreach (Font font in _fonts)
            {
                font.Dispose();
            }
            _fonts = null;
        }
        if (_foreBrush != null)
        {
            _foreBrush.Dispose();
            _foreBrush = null;
        }
    }

    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ForeColor;
        }
        set
        {
            base.ForeColor = value;
            if (_foreBrush != null)
            {
                _foreBrush.Dispose();
            }
            _foreBrush = null;
        }
    }

    private Brush ForeBrush
    {
        get
        {
            if (_foreBrush == null)
            {
                _foreBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor);
            }
            return _foreBrush;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
        if (e.Index < 0)
            return;

        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        Rectangle bounds = e.Bounds;
        Font font = (Font)Items[e.Index];
        e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, ForeBrush, bounds.Left, bounds.Top);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. You already know how to check which styles are available for each font. Just add the style checkbuttons and enable only those which are available for the selected font.

Comment: @Rotem This can only check for the basic font styles like italic,bold,underline and regular.There will be extra styles available for different fonts ,how can i check those.

Comment: @techno what other styles are you trying to test for? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Udomaki Bold italic,Oblique etc

Comment: @techno wouldn't a font that support bold and italic support bold italic? I am not sure what oblique is. How would you specify this style for a font if it is not part of the FontStyle enumeration?

Comment: @Rotem These styles are shown in default font dialog and you can use these styles eventhough the enumneration FontStyle does not include them like fondialog.font.style

Comment: @techno I see. Perhaps you should rephrase your question to ask how to assign the Oblique style to a font or to check if a font supports it. As far as I can tell, that is your only obstacle.